# Do MLT queries in Elasticsearch use term vectors?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Do [more like this queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) in Elasticsearch make use of term vectors if these ar activated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The underlying Lucene MLT implementation also provides [`setMaxNumTokensParsed`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.html#setMaxNumTokensParsed(int)) to provide some control over performance when term vectors are not available.